# Toggle string and regex replacement

Tags: key-bindings, query-replace

How can I quickly toggle between string and regexp versions of functions such as `replace-string`/`replace-regexp`, `query-replace`/`query-replace-regexp` etc? Pretty sure I saw a shortcut once but now I cant find it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean.  The `replace-` functions are not usually bound to any key, while the `query-replace-` ones are bound to `M-%` and `C-M-%`, respectively. Isn't that already quick enough? It seems to me that remembering the state of some toggle just adds to your cognitive burden.

Comment: I find `C-M-%` a bit difficult to press so most of the time I go for `M-x` and type `query-replace-regexp` manually. Most of the time I use `query-replace` (via `M-%`) but sometimes it would be easier to press `M-%` and then something else to switch to `query-replace-regexp` instead.

Comment: In that case, I'd be tempted to turn `M-%` into a prefix key and bind `query-replace` to `M-% s` (`s` for string) and `query-replace-regexp` to `M-% r`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Harald, I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect.

But FWIW, I think the best way to perform such operations is with:

```
C-s <string1> M-% <string2> RET
```

in which case the answer is that you can use `M-r` any time between the `C-s` and the `M-%` to toggle between string search and regexp search.
You can similarly use `M-c` to toggle the case-sensitivity.

Comment: I was not aware of the power of `isearch-forward`. But it looks like `M-r` only toggles the search mode, while you still must use `C-M-%` to run `query-replace-regexp`? (Unless the docstring for `isearch-forward` is wrong.) What would be nice is if `M-%` in this context chose between the two replace commands to match the current search mode – oh, wait, experimentation reveals that it does so! That's a documentation bug, then.

Comment: Also, if you know you want to start with a regexp isearch and you find `C-M-s` awkward, by default you can alternatively use `C-u C-s`. Although depending on your keyboard `C-s M-r` may still be easier than either of those.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I just tested it and `M-%` does start `query-replace-regexp` if you use it from a regexp isearch.